# show navigation drawer on physical menu button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to show the navigation drawer when the user clicks on the physical menu button, I override the menu button like the following :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {

                // some code here to show navigation drawer

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But I don't know what should I do to show the navigation drawer inside this method.

Comment: You really shouldn't do this, the menu button should always open the overflow menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT) is what you are looking for. Btw I don't think that it is a bad think to do, since a lot of people is not familiar with the drawer yet.

Comment: i thought it would be a bad practice since people usually use the menu button to show the "settings" menu.

Comment: You are correct @Opetmar, the menu button should be used for the overflow menu and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of against Googles guidlines, but since they don't actually use the guidelines in their own apps... I would rather make users happy, than Google :)

Comment: Following the guidelines would make users happier, because that's what they are used to! To make users familiar with the navigation drawer you could open the drawer automatically when the user opens the app for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, opening the drawer on starup is a good idea. I am just about to release my app, and the testers had a really hard time finding the other screens available from the drawer.

Comment: For anyone discovering this answer after 2015: now everybody knows how drawers work, so I don't think it is necessary any more to do hacks like this.

Comment: `myDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)` to support also RTL screens.

Comment: I'm correcting myself: `myDrawerLayout.operDrawer(GravityCompat.START)` to support also RTL screens.

Answer (score 2):

Well, somewhere in your layout you have a DrawerLayout, which consists of your main view and your navigation drawer view.

Now you can do ...

```
final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
final View navigation = ((NavigationDrawer)drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer));

if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigation)) drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigation);
else drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigation);
```

Comment: since @Ripityom answerd my question first i had to accept his answer , but anyway thank you.